# Getting the value of foreach loop with 2 or more condition

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert multiple record from my HTML form to my Database Using PHP
i just learn that it is possible to have foreach loop with 2 or more condition now my problem is how can i get those value and insert it to my database?
here is my sample code:

```
 while($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
   // this loop has more than 1 data to fetch
 ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="studName[]" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="studId[]" value="">
   <input type="" name="text1[]" value="">
 <?php
 }
```

Now getting each value from this textbox array, here is my code:

```
 foreach (array($text1, $studName, $studId) as $data) {
  //qry for inserting value from array in one table
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the variable this way. (if all arrays are the same size).

```
foreach($text1 as $key => $text){
   echo $text1[$key];
   echo $studName[$key];
   echo $studId[$key];
}
```

Comment: your loop is as big as $text1 array elements so if $studName got more elements not every element is used and if $studName got more elements as $text1 an error is shown

Comment: my bad just read the opening question again your array's are all the same size so you can use this to insert your data